Spyder5 - how to change background color of panes (Help, Variable ..., Plots,Files)
Is there any possiblity to change background color of panes window in Spyder5, in Linux Ubuntu 22.04?
The background color could be easily changed for editor and python console - but I'm unable to find any way how it could be done for the panes.

I tried to make same experiments with GTK_THEME but I haven't obtained any effect.
It is possible to change the background color of these panes and how?
